# Removing TK from Window Title Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, window, tk-toolkit

I re-used a code I found here to set the transparency to the TK icon, but it leaves the TK there in the invoked window. I created a second window, and I am able to edit that title. But why can't I edit the code I found from an existing post. I looked everywhere but the new window I made, the title can be edited, why not the other window with Tk in it?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import tempfile

ICON = (b'\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x10\x10\x00\x00\x01\x00\x08\x00h\x05\x00\x00'
    b'\x16\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x01\x00'
    b'\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
    b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01') + b'\x00'*1282 + b'\xff'*64

_, ICON_PATH = tempfile.mkstemp()
with open(ICON_PATH, 'wb') as icon_file:
    icon_file.write(ICON)

root = Tk()

root.title("rename")    

tk = tkinter.Tk()
tk.iconbitmap(default=ICON_PATH)
label = tkinter.Label(tk, text="Window with transparent icon.")
label.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have two `Tk` objects. Don't do that.

Comment: I know I have two tkinter imports, but I'm just about ready to say destroy the one window or hide it. And use the second window.

Comment: You have two `Tk` _objects_: `root` and `tk`. You should not be doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should not create multiple `Tk()` applications in the same program.

The issue occurs because you create the new window (Application) using `Tk()` , but you are renaming the title only `root` application. This does not rename the title of `tk` application. That you create.

If all you want is for the title to be renamed for the window with the label - *Window with transparent icon.* . You should use `tk.title()` (instead of `root.title()`) . Example -

```
import tkinter
import tempfile

ICON = (b'\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x10\x10\x00\x00\x01\x00\x08\x00h\x05\x00\x00'
    b'\x16\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x01\x00'
    b'\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
    b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01') + b'\x00'*1282 + b'\xff'*64

_, ICON_PATH = tempfile.mkstemp()
with open(ICON_PATH, 'wb') as icon_file:
    icon_file.write(ICON)
tk = tkinter.Tk()
tk.title("rename")
tk.iconbitmap(default=ICON_PATH)
label = tkinter.Label(tk, text="Window with transparent icon.")
label.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

And you do not need multiple `tkinter` imports, it does not do anything. Importing `tkinter` (or any module) once caches it in `sys.modules` , and any time you try to import it again, you get that cached module from `sys.modules` .

---

If you want to create more windows in your application you should use [`Toplevel` widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) for that . Example -

```
import tkinter
import tempfile

ICON = (b'\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x10\x10\x00\x00\x01\x00\x08\x00h\x05\x00\x00'
    b'\x16\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x01\x00'
    b'\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
    b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01') + b'\x00'*1282 + b'\xff'*64

_, ICON_PATH = tempfile.mkstemp()
with open(ICON_PATH, 'wb') as icon_file:
    icon_file.write(ICON)

tk = tkinter.Tk()
tk.title("rename")

tknewwindow = tkinter.Toplevel(tk)
tknewwindow.title("rename1")
tknewwindow.iconbitmap(default=ICON_PATH)

label = tkinter.Label(tknewwindow, text="Window with transparent icon.")
label.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm just starting with GUI applications and Tkinter. I think this should be starred for people looking to take away the Tk in their windows.